# How to access specific information in json?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I made an authentication method in a WEB API and I'm getting the answer below:

```
I/Response 
{
"login": "teste@teste.com", 
"senha": "12345dxkjs", 
"token":"kjqwdjqwdjlqkwjqkwdjqwdjwdqkwjlqjwkdqwjl", ....
}
```

I use the code below to read the information:

```
String data = response.body().string();
Log.e("response", data);
```

How can I access only the token that is in the array?
How do I do this using java/android?

Comment: That looks like json so parse it as such instead

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm trying to use JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject(data),  but without success!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use some JSON library, e.g. [org.json](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) to parse the string first.
In your case the code to get the token would like something like this:

```
import org.json.*;
    
try
{
    String data = response.body().string();
    JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject(data);
    
    String token = jsonData.getString("token");
    Log.e("response", token);
}
catch (JSONException e)
{
     Log.e("JSON Exception", e);
}
```

Comment: Unhandled exception: org.json.JSONException. surround with try/catch

Comment: @EdrianBiagi As the exception says, you should surround your code with try/catch. More specifically - the JSONObject. I've updated the answer. Enjoy. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this command

```java
String data = response.body().string();
JSONObject Jobject = new JSONObject(data);
Log.e("response", Jobject.getString("token"));
```

After parsing the string to the JSONObject you can access any item in the JSON, like 'token'.

Comment: Unhandled exception: org.json.JSONException - The option appears: surround try catch